# Order By Date ASC with Spring Data

Tags: java, sql, spring, postgresql, spring-data

I try to make an application with Spring-Data-JPA on a table in order by ASC but it gives me an error:

```
Invalid derived query! No property asc found for type java.util.Calendar
```

Why ?

```
List<Foo> findAllOrderByDateAsc();
```

or

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY date ASC")
List<Foo> findAllOrderByDateAsc();
```

Answer (score 182, accepted):

Try to add "By" between "All" and "Order" like this:

```
List<Foo> findAllByOrderByDateAsc();
```

Comment: the trick with this answer is that is not necessary to write the @Query but just by naming the method in the right way Spring-data will generate the query ok

Comment: For me, this changes the IllegalArgumentException to a NullPointerException thrown by QueryUtils.toExpressionRecursively(). I am not using an @Query.

Comment: How can i give the colomn name is dynamically getting from front end.??

Comment: Of all the brilliant abstractions the Spring framework provides to us, it turns out they're not yet there with grammar.

Comment: Related [bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-814) was closed as "Works as Designed".

Answer (score 11):

I don't think you can use findAll as a prefix.

Regarding the query, `select *` is not valid JPQL. It should be

```
select foo from Foo foo order by foo.date desc
```

Comment: Why doesn't it solve the problem? The problem is that the query is invalid, and I tell him what the correct query is.

Answer (score 5):

Example :

```
databaseDAO.findByUserNameOrderByCreatedDateDesc(username);
```

to list out users based on username and sortby created date.

```
@Repository
public interface DatabaseDAO extends JpaRepository<User,Integer> {

public List<RecentlyView>  findByUserNameOrderByCreatedDateDesc(String username);


}
```

Answer (score 2):

`date` is reserved word in SQL. Try changing the table property to `foo_date`, for example and rewrite your query as `SELECT * FROM foo ORDER BY foo_date DESC`

Comment: That's not SQL. It's JPQL.

Comment: Correct. My bad. @MaximeF see http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.0.0.M1/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

Comment: its not working @Query("SELECT f FROM foo f ORDER BY f.date DESC")

Comment: What is the exception?

Comment: Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: foo is not mapped [SELECT f FROM foo f ORDER BY f.date DESC]

Comment: @MaximeF: Java is case sensitive. The name of the class is Foo, not foo.

Comment: It is written in PgAdmin foo. Not Foo