# NPE when declaring new query method in CrudRepository

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am implementing a feature that returns top record from the database in an existing application used in weather monitoring. I am using Spring, Hibernate, Spring Data JPA.

Spring version is `4.1.1 RELEASE`. Here's the minimal example:

`Reading` entity:

```
@Entity
public class Reading {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private Date time;
    private double temperature;

    //getters, setters
}
```

`ReadingController`:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/reading")
public class ReadingController {
    @Autowired
    private ReadingDao readingDao;

    //controller logic
}
```

The DAO I am using:

```
public interface ReadingDao extends CrudRepository<Reading, Long>{
    Reading findTopByOrderByTemperatureDesc();

    //other methods
}
```

I have also configured Spring to look for components in the `mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml` file:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.mycompany"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

**The problem**: adding the `findTopByOrderByTemperatureDesc()` method to the `ReadingDao` causes a `NullPointerException` while autowiring the `ReadingDao` in `ReadingController`.

According to the [Spring Data JPA documentation (chapter 3.4.5)](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result) the method should work.

Also, the name of the method seems to be correct (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733464/order-by-date-desc-with-spring-data)). I tried with `findTopOrderByTemperatureDesc`, and `findTopByTemperatureDesc`, but got `No property desc found for type double`.

Stacktrace:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'readingController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private org.mycompany.dao.ReadingDao org.mycompany.controller.ReadingController.readingDao; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'readingDao': FactoryBean threw exception on object creation; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1204)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:229)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:725)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:629)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:677)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:548)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1279)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1087)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5493)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:632)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1740)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:618)
    at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:565)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:301)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1471)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1312)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1404)
    at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:832)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$79(TCPTransport.java:683)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**Note** that the application is working properly when that method is not declared, and there are no problems during autowiring.

How to solve this problem? Or how to implement the same feature in some other way?

EDIT: I also have

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="org.mycompany.dao"/>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>
```

in `Datasource.xml` file that configures the database and repositories.

EDIT2: I also changed `double` to `Double` as suggested, but that did not change anything.

Comment: does your interface has `@Component` or `@Repository` annotation?

Comment: No, but adding them does not change anything (just checked).

Comment: Could you try extending JpaRepository instead of CrudRepository.

Comment: You have `findTopByOrderByTemperatureDesc` the first `By` should specify a field you want to use for searching, if you don't want remove the first `by`.

Comment: Extending JpaRepository gives the same error. Changing the method name to `findTopByTemperatureDesc` as well as `findTopOrderByTemperatureDesc` still gives the same error.

Comment: Do you have: `<jpa:repositories base-package="org.mycompany" />` somehwere ? http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods

Comment: Yes, I do have a `Datasource.xml` file with that.

Comment: Alternately, you can try to write the query manually using @Query on the query method.

Comment: How can I limit the number of rows to one using @Query?

Comment: Try changing `double` to `Double`. Also do you have a getter?

Comment: Yes, I do have a getter. This is just a minimal example. Are you sure that changing `double` to `Double` will work? I think I will have to rebuild the whole database for that. Note that I have other methods in the `ReadingDao` and they work fine. Nonetheless, I will try this.

Comment: Which version of `spring-data` do you have? I believe `findTop`/`findFirst` were introduced in version `1.8`, if you have an older one that can be the cause.

Comment: You are right. I will accept the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.company.product.repository" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager" />
```

Or

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.company.product.repository", entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManager", transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager")
```

You must configure the jpa repositories, and this package should contain all your repo classes. In your case the ReadingDao should be placed in the repo package example (com.company.product.repository)

```
<context:component-scan base-package="org.mycompany"/>
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.company.product.repository" entity-manager-factory-ref="entityManagerFactory" transaction-manager-ref="transactionManager" />
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but I already have it all configured (see my edit). The application is working, the error occurs **only** when I add the `findTopByOrderByTemperatureDesc` method to the dao interface.