# @Embedded in OrderBy query in method signature

Tags: java, spring, jpa, crud

I have an Entity(lets consider Workplace ) with an type field and  Embedded field
eg.

```
@Embedded
private WorkplaceAddress workplaceAddress;
```

and it contains fields

```
@Embeddable
class WorkplaceAddress {

private String street;

private String city;
}
```

//etc

And now I would like make a query in the methodSignature:
I tried:

```
List<Workplace> findAllOrderByWorkplaceAddressStreetAscWorkplaceAddressCityAsc 
List<Workplace> findAllOrderByWorkplaceAddress_StreetAscWorkplaceAddress_CityAsc //considered as field not Ascending
List<Workplace> findAllOrderByWorkplaceAddress_Street_AscWorkplaceAddress_City_Asc
List<Workplace> findAllByTypeOrderByWorkplaceAddress_StreetAscWorkplaceAddress_CityAsc
```

Is this feature available yet?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Order By Date ASC with Spring Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19733464/order-by-date-asc-with-spring-data)